# Read an element within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xss, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm building an Edge extension. I'm trying to get the exact same element as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68613600/selenium-only-finding-certain-elements-in-python/68613888) asks, but I want to use JS, not Selenium.
[Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaIj2.png)

I'm running the JS through my extension's background script. In the future, I would like the popup to have a button and that button to read the syllable on screen.

The provided solution is in Selenium and I'd like to transpile it into JS.
`driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='game']/iframe[contains(@src,'jklm.fun')]"))`

If none of this works, I guess I'll have to use optical text recognition.

Here's `manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "myName",
    "description": "myDescription",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {
        "128": "myIcon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://jklm.fun/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "js/myScript.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside `js` folder, here's `myScript.js`

```
console.log('myscript is running')

const syllableHandler = () => { 
    const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
    console.log(iframe?.[0]?.contentWindow)
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', syllableHandler)
```

Comment: That is optional chaining in case there is no such iframe.
[Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#syntax)

Comment: You can use code like this to get the DOM element in the iframe: `document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document`, and then use the css selector to get the element you need. But you need to make sure that the website and the iframe are loaded in the same domain, due to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).